# Error with addEventListener in Pixi.js: "Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'" TypeScript

Tags: typescript, pixi.js

I'm developing a web application using Pixi.js, and I'm encountering the following error when using the addEventListener method:

`Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'`

Here's a snippet of the relevant code:

```
import { Application, Texture, ParticleContainer } from 'pixi.js';
import { Emitter, upgradeConfig } from '@pixi/particle-emitter';
import * as particleSettings from "./emitter.json";

const particleContainer = new ParticleContainer();

const app = new Application({
  view: document.getElementById("pixi-canvas") as HTMLCanvasElement,
  resolution: window.devicePixelRatio || 1,
  autoDensity: true,
  backgroundColor: 0x6495ed,
  width: 640,
  height: 480
});

// ...

app.view.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
  // ...
});
```

I'm getting an error when calling the addEventListener method, indicating that app.view might be undefined. I've confirmed that the element is correctly retrieved using document.getElementById("pixi-canvas"). I've also made sure that I'm using the latest versions of Pixi.js and its related modules.

I would appreciate any advice on identifying the cause of this error or suggestions on how to resolve it.

Additional information:

I've verified that the  element with the ID "pixi-canvas" exists in the HTML.
I'm using Pixi.js and its related modules with the latest versions.
Any guidance on how to resolve this error or insights into the potential cause would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I had changed it to 
`const canvas = document.getElementById("pixi-canvas") as HTMLCanvasElement;
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
});`
it worked
Upon investigating the error message, it seems that app.view could be undefined. To avoid this error, is there a way to capture the mouse click event without referencing app.view?